# ajax requests stops on back button even user choose to stay on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blueimp

I am uploading files using bluimp library which makes Ajax request. Now, when user clicks back button by mistake (which is so obvious in Mac) when file upload is in progress, user losses all data and redirects to previous page.

To stop this, I have written below code.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "You will loss all recently added/edited data.";
  if(window.displayUnloadAlert) {
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
  }
});
```

Using below code, user is not able to navigate back to previous page by mistake as it displays alert before page unloads but issue is even User choose to stay on same page, all ajax request to upload files stops. How can I prevent that? (This issue comes on Safari and Chrome. Firefox keeps ajax request on.)

Also, after some testing, i come to know that chrome and safari don't kill ajax request on Reload button but kills on back button after using above code.

Comment: As i'm aware, there is no cross browser way of doing something like that, unfortunately. I hope someone else knows a workaround

Comment: After searching a lot, I have found that one other user have already posted similar issue a year back here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236146/chrome-back-button-terminates-upload-stream-unexpectedly but there is no solution given for this. Please help me.